# Remove PE (Portable Executable) Command Line

Tags: command-line, portable-executable

How to remove some unused Command Line parameters from an executable? example: i have a EXE that using this following command line (**-a, -b, -c, -1, -2, -3**) how do i remove "**-2**" command? i've try to use **RES Editor**, **HEX Editor** and **EXE Disassembler**, but nothing. someone can help me? what the program must i use for this? because if i remove the "**GetCommandLine(A/W)**" function, it lost all commands. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to reverse engineer the executable, find where it checks for those arguments and remove the relevant code (e.g. by replacing it with NOPs).

An easier option is to provide a wrapper executable that would sanitize the command line and call the original, unmodified, executable just with the options you want to preserve.

Comment: @faid: You'd have to write one.

Comment: How to? i'm newbie in exe modifier!

Comment: did you mean write in C/Cpp?